# How to set appropriate zoom value in mouse_input for the sendInput method of User32.dll?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mouse, mousewheel, kinect-sdk

I am using Kinect to play around with a website(JS). That website has a 3d graph on it which can be interacted with. Left click and moving around rotates it while mouse wheel rotation increases/decreases its size. I want to do all this using a Kinect.

The problem I am facing is

1) I have given the zoom value i.e the dwData in mouse_event as the distance between right wrist and left wrist. This is making the zoom in zoom out happen but at a very slow pace I tried multiplying the zoom value with higher numbers and it did not work. Here is the relevant piece of code

```
internal struct MouseInput
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public float MouseData;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

internal struct Input
    {
        public int Type;
        public MouseInput MouseInput;
    }

Input[] i = new Input[1];

i[0] = new Input();
i[0].Type = InputMouse;
i[0].MouseInput.Flags = MouseEventWheel;
i[0].MouseInput.MouseData = zoomVal * 1000;

uint result = SendInput(3, i, Marshal.SizeOf(i[0]));
```

In the above code, zoomVal comes from the distance between the left and right wrist. I keep it as it is or multiply it with 1000, it still zooms at a very slow rate.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public float MouseData;
```

That's the wrong type, the MOUSEINPUT.mouseData field is actually a DWORD in Windows.  Simply an *int* in C#.  Something you can see in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Or the [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MOUSEINPUT.html) article, usually a pretty decent place to find good pinvoke declarations (YMMV).

The outcome is pretty random, your C# code will generate an IEEE-754 formatted single precision floating point value but Windows/Kinect will read it as an integer.  "Very slow rate" is certainly very likely, multiplying the value will only increment the bits in the value that represent the exponent.

Make it `public int MouseData;` instead to get ahead.